# Check whether an element is displayed inline or block

Tags: html, parsing, html-agility-pack

I'm currently using HtmlAgilityPack to parse some HTML files and I would like to know if there is a way to detect if an HtmlAgilityPack node is an inline/block element or it is displayed inline/block. Thanks.

Comment: Probably better to ask on the project's Discussions page: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/discussions.

Comment: Assuming you mean  by default rather then due to some sort of css rule? check out MDN block level elements page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements